# neo4j subqueries in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I cypher queries are beginners.
I want to query is as follows

data insert

```
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 1 , phone_num : "1" } );  //[1]
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 2 , phone_num : "2" } );  //[2]
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 3 , phone_num : "3" } );  //[3]
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 4 , phone_num : "4" } );  //[4]


CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 5 , phone_num : "5" } ); //[5]
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 6 , phone_num : "6" } ); //[6]
CREATE ( USER{ talk_id : 7 , phone_num : "7" } ); //[7]

START s=node(1) , d=node(2) CREATE s-[r:FRIEND]->d RETURN r;
START s=node(1) , d=node(3) CREATE s-[r:FRIEND]->d RETURN r;
START s=node(1) , d=node(4) CREATE s-[r:FRIEND]->d RETURN r;

START s=node(2) , d=node(7) CREATE s-[r:FRIEND]->d RETURN r;
```

quering

query 1 :

```
START s=node(1) match s-[r]->f return f;
```

result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| f                                |
+----------------------------------+
| Node[2]{talk_id:2,phone_num:"2"} |
| Node[3]{talk_id:3,phone_num:"3"} |
| Node[4]{talk_id:4,phone_num:"4"} |
+----------------------------------+
```

query 2

```
start s = node( 2, 3 , 4 ) , s1 = node( 2 , 3 , 4 ) match p=s-[r]->s1 return s1;
```

**i want relation node of s  and intersection s1;**

result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| s                                | 
+----------------------------------+
| Node[3]{talk_id:3,phone_num:"3"} |
+----------------------------------+
1 row
```

I want to combine the two into one query  and result

ex )

```
+----------------------------------+
| f                                |
+----------------------------------+
| Node[2]{talk_id:2,phone_num:"2"} |
| Node[3]{talk_id:3,phone_num:"3"} |
| Node[4]{talk_id:4,phone_num:"4"} |
| Node[3]{talk_id:3,phone_num:"3"} |
+----------------------------------+
```

What should I do, but?
RDBMS just like the subquery

TANK YOU ^^;

Comment: don't understand the question. Please refine.

Comment: SORRY. be poor at English. EDIT my Question. please Answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Based on that I can guess two cases you're asking for

1) you want to use the result of the first query as starting point for a second query and combine that into a single query:

```
start s=node(1)
match s-[r1]->()-[r2]->f
return f
```

N.B. a `path`, the expression after the `match` might have an arbitrary length.

You can also split it and chain the subqueries using `with`

```
start s=node(1)
match s-[r1]->t
with t
match t-[r2]->f
return f
```

2) you want to combine the result of two different queries into a single result set. In this case you have to use the [`UNION`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/) keyword being introduced in Neo4j 2.0 or do this on client side.

Comment: Answer Thank you. But this is not what I asked. re edit my question